# iOS 9.3 offline dictation not working

Tags: ios, siri, voice-dictation

I have an iPad Pro 12.9 and an iPhone 6s, both have "hey siri" enabled, along with dictation. However I can't get the offline dictation to show up. I initially thought it was because I live in Italy (but I have everything set to US English), so I tried wiping the iPad and just setting up everything without logging in to any Apple account. I set the location to USA and the language to US English, but I still can't get offline dictation. Any suggestions?

Comment: BTW, Apple Pay and News are available (since I set it up as a US iPad, but no offline dictation). These are not available in Italy, they only pop up when I set the region to USA.

Answer (score 1):

**I think I solved this!!!!**

I have an iPhone 6s+ and iPad Pro, neither of which allowed offline dictation.

For some reason, **the language package which allows your iPhone 6s(+) or iPad Pro to do offline dictation appears to be downloaded *alongside* of any of *Siri's* English dialects**.

Discovered this semi-accidentally. I had a weird-and-shouldn't-work epiphany this morning. I had an American English keyboard but prefer Siri's British voice. I wondered if it would only download if the keyboard preference and Siri dialect were the same. Changed the dialect to American English (which I had to download), restarted the phone, and viola, offline dictation was enabled.

Tried the same on my iPad, but it didn't work.

But then I realized that Siri's American English was already loaded on my iPad, so I tried downloading the Australian dialect, and voila!, offline dictation was now enabled.

**It appears that downloading any English dialect for Siri will also download the offline dictation package.**

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Siri is different from dictation.
 Siri is for asking questions and commands. 
 Of course you can ask Siri to spell something.
 On your keyboard between emoji key and the Space bar is the microphone listen key. Press & speek.  Job done I hope. I am not speaking from experience  because my iPad Air is not capable of doing this. Hope to buy a new iPad next week on the strength of it being capable of off-line dictation.
 I rely on online dictation at the moment but I would like to do it off-line as I am extremely dyslexic.